# How can I customise an attribute of a div or an HTML element that is adding style like a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I want esilizar an attribute to be able to make a tooltip or something like gender do to style with css?

example

```
<div data-tolltip="Some info" class="base">
    Some div container
</div>
```

Comment: you want to make tooltip in css??

Comment: I'm sorry I did not put the css tag on this question but with css thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS tooltip code:

```css
div[data-tolltip] { position:relative; display:inline-block;}
div[data-tolltip]:before { position:absolute; bottom:100%; left:10px; margin-bottom:-9px; content:""; width:0; height:0; border:9px solid transparent; border-top-color:#000; z-index:55555; display:none;}
div[data-tolltip]:after { position:absolute; bottom:100%; left:-5px; padding:8px 10px; margin-bottom:9px; content:attr(data-tolltip); display:none; background:#000; color:#fff; font:600 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; z-index:55555; border-radius:3px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
div[data-tolltip]:hover:before { display:block;}
div[data-tolltip]:hover:after { display:block;}

.base { margin-top:50px; margin-left:50px;}/*not required, It's for demo*/
```

```html
<div data-tolltip="Some info" class="base">
    Some div container
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
}
div:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="Some info" class="base">
  Some div container
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot now it's just me stylize my way, thank you